# Getting a contact by email using the sendgrid api

Tags: sql, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm trying to retrieve contact  id by email using the sendgrid 'Contacts API'. It looks like the way to do this is to POST to the `/marketing/contacts/search` endpoint.

I'm not familiar with SQL, does anybody know how I'd query the email field as explained here:
https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/contacts/search-contacts

Answer (score 1):

on the link that you  provide there is a tab that is called "try it out" click there and you can try it out. Just add your Api token and there is already a query that you just need to add the email address

```
    {
        "query": "email LIKE 'ENTER_COMPLETE_OR_PARTIAL_EMAIL_ADDRESS_HERE'"
    }
```

if you are adding a partial email address just add % before or/and after (depending which side is missing info)

Comment: Is there any way to add the email from a stored variable. Such as let email = user.name

Comment: something like this {"query": "email like " + user.name}

Comment: Thanks Lys! This was answered here if anyone else is trying to figure out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69408873/search-contacts-with-sendgrid-api