# Search Contacts with SendGrid API

Tags: node.js, express, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/contacts/search-contacts

I'm attempting to search for a contact as shown in SendGrids docs above. In the body section below I'd like to change the hard coded "andrew@gmail.com" to be a variable. Such as `email = req.user.email;` What is the correct way to do that? Just setting the variable and dropping in 'email' does not work.

```
    var request = require("request");

    var options = { method: 'POST',
    
    url: 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts/search',
    headers: 
    { 'content-type': 'application/json',
    authorization: 'Bearer SG.key' },
    body: { query: 'email LIKE \'andrew@gmail.com\' AND CONTAINS(list_ids, \'6bcc2d0c-ea17-41ba-a4a1-962badsasdas1\')' },
    json: true };
    
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    
    console.log(body);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

Try using [string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) using back ticks (which, as an added bonus, means you don't have to escape your single quotes), like below:

```js
const email = req.user.email;
const body = `email LIKE '${email}' AND CONTAINS(list_ids, '6bcc2d0c-ea17-41ba-a4a1-962badsasdas1')`;

const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/contacts/search',
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    authorization: 'Bearer SG.key'
  },
  body: { query: query },
  json: true
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
if (error) throw new Error(error);

console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: This does seem to be in fact working. I was adding the email to the marketing list and then immediately searching for it. It seems to take a few minutes before being able to search for the email like above. Thanks for the help!

Comment: From SendGrid: There is indeed a time to wait while the contacts are uploaded to your SendGrid account. It depends mostly on how many contacts you have uploaded, but we regularly recommend waiting up to 5 minutes before you can search for them through the API or email them using an associated list

Comment: Yeah, when you upload contacts SendGrid starts a job to import the contacts. If you [upload via the API](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/contacts/add-or-update-a-contact) you should receive a job ID in response. You can then [check the status of that job with this API](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/contacts/import-contacts-status).

Comment: This is awesome Phil thank you!